# Ubuntu shell not being able type password

Tags: command-line, password

Ok this all have started because I was stuck in the login loop, and when I search up online for solutions for it, almost all of the videos I see is using the shell, which is the terminal for Ubuntu. So I got in Ubuntu terminal, put in my name, press enter. Type in my password, then nothing shows up. I have looked online for answers on why my password was not showing up and most people says that it wont show up and you just have to type it in and enter it, then it will let me in, but it did not. Once I pressed enter, it just goes down a line and does nothing. Anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Welcome! I had the same issue, Do you have one or more disks?

Comment: Yes, I have an ssd and a HDD

Comment: When this happened to me it ment that my Hard drive was broken